# force the arrays inside n dimensional array to have the same size

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in python and I need to give the same size to my arrays inside my n dimensional array (narray) :
My initial array:

```
[array([  6.27963604e-04,   3.58836345e-04,   1.79418172e-04,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   8.97090862e-05,
         8.97090862e-05])],  [array([  4.64746103e-04,   4.35699472e-05,   2.90466315e-05,
         4.35699472e-05,   8.71398944e-05,   1.45233157e-05,
         0.00000000e+00,   1.45233157e-05,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.45233157e-05])],  [array([  8.71113726e-04,   7.85430409e-05,   6.78326262e-05,
         3.92715204e-05,   1.78506911e-05,   1.78506911e-05,
         1.78506911e-05,   7.14027644e-06,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.07104147e-05,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   3.57013822e-06])]]
```

The output that I want : I want to get n array with arrays that has 7 elements in each by removing the other elements and forcing each array to have 7 as size :

```
[array([  6.27963604e-04,   3.58836345e-04,   1.79418172e-04,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   8.97090862e-05,
         8.97090862e-05])],[array([  4.64746103e-04,   4.35699472e-05,   2.90466315e-05,
         4.35699472e-05,   8.71398944e-05,   1.45233157e-05,
         0.00000000e+00])], [array([  8.71113726e-04,   7.85430409e-05,   6.78326262e-05,
         3.92715204e-05,   1.78506911e-05,   1.78506911e-05,
         1.78506911e-05])]
```

Thank you ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have list of numpy arrays, in that case you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> narray = [np.arange(np.random.randint(7,10)) for i in range (5)]
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])]

>>> clipped_arr = [a[:7] for a in narray]
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]
```